# xhr.onload too slow in android

Tags: javascript, android, xmlhttprequest

I need to display image/jpeg in my web application as well as android app with same code and used the below working javascript code for the same:

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open('GET', value, true);
     xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
      xhr.onload = function (e) {
                    var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array( this.response );
                    var blob = new Blob( [ arrayBufferView ], { type: "image/jpeg" } );
                    var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                    localSrc = urlCreator.createObjectURL( blob );
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.src=localSrc;
                    $('#jpg'+i).append(img);
       };
        xhr.send();
```

The performance is too slow when tested in android 4.4.2, like its waiting to send the xhr request after collecting all the image url's. Delay is more in android compared to web application .

**How can I improve the performance ? Is there any other method to do the same with better performance?**

Comment: It is just a caching issue. After clearing the cache It will be faster .

Comment: I don't think its a caching issue , i tried by clearing the cache also. Same result as above

Comment: see the answer.